# Mail send framework for iphone

Tags: iphone, email

I want to send emails with attachments from my iphone application with custom UI. What can i use for this?

UPD: maybe it's possible to use some smtp library for this task? What can you advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to do the following
first add a framework by right clicking on project.
Add -> Existing Framework -> 
library/frameworks/MessageUI.framework

then
in ViewController.h file

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController  <UITextFieldDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>{
//....yor variables
}
```

**ViewController.m file**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

self.title = @"Sample Email Application"; // title of navigation bar

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose target:self action:@selector(composeMail:)] autorelease]; // for adding a compose button 
//in navigation bar.
//...your code 
}


-(void) composeMail: (id) sender{
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[[picker navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];


[picker setSubject:@"Sample Email Application"];
[picker setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Visit for more help %@. ",@"http://google.com"] isHTML:YES];

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
}



- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{
[controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: You missed a crucial point of the original question: `custom UI` ..Apple doesn't want you to modify the UI for `MFMailComposer` and you'd likely get rejected for trying to do so.  They don't even like you to change the tint of the nav bar when the modal view shows.

Comment: i can fill MFMailComposer with data from my custom UI, thanks (:

Answer (score 1):

You will need to compile in your own SMTP server, there are a few online that work. This is a pile of hurt.  Just use the iPhones Message Composer which is standard.  Unless you are building a email spam client this wont really work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send email without using the native mail composer UI and without setting up your own SMTP server, you can check out PostageApp (http://postageapp.com/). There's an iOS / Mac API wrapper that lets you send email through the API. https://github.com/postageapp/postageapp-objc

(Disclosure: I work for PostageApp and developed the plugin.)

Answer (score 0):

The open source `three20` framework has designed it's own Mail capabilities via `TTMessageController`  which mimics the original Mail app..You can use that as a starting point and then simply modify the UI of it to your needs.

E-mailing attachments is another story though...

More information: http://www.three20.info/overview